# Get PHP $_SESSION data in .htaccess for LiteSpeed cache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, litespeed

I need to send data from `$_SESSION` from PHP file to .htaccess for setup Vary variable for setting LiteSpeed cache.

PHP script example:

```
<?php $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];?>
```

.htaccess example

```
...
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
CacheLookup public on
CacheLookup private on
RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:max-age=604800]
RewriteRule .* - [E=cache-control:vary=**!!!HERE I NEED TO HAVE $lang value!!!**]
</IfModule>
...
```

**I already tried these ways:**

1. Via cookies. I set PHP variable in the cookies and get it from there in .htaccess via `"RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (.*) [NC]"`. But I will have also private data which I can't set in the cookies. So this approach is not very good.
2. Via ENV variables `(putenv("PROVARY=".$_SESSION['lang']);)`. But it does not work. Because they die at the end of the request.
3. `HTTP_SESSION`. I found this name of a module but didn't find info about how it works or even how to use it.

Is it possible to get `$_SESSION` variables from .htaccess directly? If yes, show a working example of how it works.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here, but `.htaccess` is just a file. If you want to amend it _on the fly_ then just open it, read it, amend it and rewrite it. Not sure this is a good idea but.....

Comment: I changed the title. Hope now it's more clear. I need when user makes the second request to the site, I will be able to get data from his SESSION in .htaccess.

Comment: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:lscwp:troubleshooting:php_session_and_cache

Comment: @Philipp thank you, man, it is what I was looking for. Any official comments from Litespeed. Add your comment as an answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never a good idea to cache pages, based only on session vars - especially, if the content only varies based on the language stored inside the session. Even LiteSpeed say, to [don't do so](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:lscwp:troubleshooting:php_session_and_cache)

However, you could store the language additonally inside a cookie and [vary on the cookie value](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:developer_guide:cache-vary).

For further projects I would recommend to store the language inside the uri (`example.com/en/...`, `example.com/de/...`)